# Makefile listing all files when i use %

Tags: c, linux, makefile, compilation, gnu-make

```
src/p1.c  src/p1.s

STRIPPED_FILE= $(src:%.c=%.o)

all:
    @echo $(STRIPPED_FILE)

output is src/p1.o src/p1.s
```

### Question:

Why has `$(src:%.c=%.o)` listed src/p1.s though I have given `src:%.c`

How can i get only `src/p1.o`?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to format the makefile text correctly.  Also explain why you think the output should be different -- what do you expect it to be?  Are you expecting `$(src:%.c=%.o)` to filter out the `.s` file?

Comment: Yes, I'm expecting the same